# Fractions associated with images

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The six images in the left column have a common theme.

[image]

---

***Complete the table by filling in the missing fractions.***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The missing fractions are

> **18/25** and **1/2**

The six images from top to bottom

> * **Po** (from Kung Fu panda) 
>  * **Thai** food 
>  * Shark **fin** 
>  * Kathrine **Switzer** 
>  * **Ice** cube 
>  * A person expressing **ire**

Notice now

> how each of the bold words above all can have the word **land** placed after them to form a specific nation; 
>  **Poland** 
>  **Thailand** 
>  **Finland** 
>  **Switzerland** 
>  **Iceland** 
>  **Ireland**

The fractions in the right column

> Are the [flag proportions](https://www.flagpictures.com/countries/flag-proportions/) of each country! We can see that Poland have ratio 5:8, Thailand have ratio 2:3, Finland have ratio 11:18, Switzerland have ratio 1:1, Iceland have ratio **18:25** and Ireland have ratio **1:2**